# Is denial of service possible by getting the exit node to create another circuit?

Tags: exit-policies, dos

Even though circuit length is limited to 8, can an attacker create a circuit of length 8, and then get the exit node to create another circuit of length 8 (get the exit node to be a Tor client)? Then could he repeat this to get a really long chain of circuits and flood the network?

---

**Update**: I guess this is possible unless exit policies block connections to Tor ports on entry guards, or entry guards reject exit nodes.

Comment: It's possible, why do you imagine this would create any kind of denial of service condition though?

Comment: @cacahuatl, if someone creates a long circuit (perhaps 1000-1000000 nodes long) and then floods it with traffic, then the entire network will transfer data at many multiples of his bandwidth.

Comment: There would be simpler attacks that would be more effective.

Comment: @cacahuatl, what kinds of attacks would be more effective than this simple amplification attack?

Comment: There's no real "amplification" there.

Comment: @cacahuatl, everything you send is sent again multiple times. If there were no amplification, then why would Tor restrict circuit length?

Comment: It's not a very effective attack on the Tor network compared to more traditional means of creating asymmetry and causing denial of service.

Comment: I mean, if Tor just had enough clients connecting at one then it would result in a "denial of service"...really what you're describing is making lots of client connection?

Comment: Isn't this creating asymmetry though? Unlike creating many client connections, the attacker would need just a small amount of bandwidth.

Comment: You would in effect be creating many client connections, just over Tor. So you'd be even less efficient at creating them.

Comment: Isn't this different? If you create N client connections, you would have to send N times, but with a long chain, you would just need to send once.

Comment: But you don't have a long chain, you have lots of short chains in series.

Comment: Isn't that the same? Sending one packet causes it to be sent along the series of short chains, which is equivalent to a long chain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not as efficiently as a single arbitrarily long circuit.
[Ticket 2667](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/2667) has never been fixed.

Comment: Wouldn't this be impossible to fix as long as the attacker can make Tor traffic reenter Tor, possibly through other proxies?

Comment: Yes. As arma already said it is not a very effective fix. On the other hand, as you need to reenter the network, the attack becomes less effective since each separate circuit has some overhead, which limits the amplification. For example, if you chain 3 circuits together, you have to send about 6 KiB to deliver a cell to the exit node in the last circuit. Thus the actual amplification is limited by the throughput of the first circuit.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible but relays won't do it.

Tor uses "relay early" cell, which is used to prevent people from building very long paths in the Tor network. Very long paths can be used to induce congestion and aid in breaking anonymity.

It has been addressed in this proposal [avoid-infinite-circuits](https://github.com/torproject/torspec/blob/master/proposals/110-avoid-infinite-circuits.txt)

> An attacker can add load to the Tor network by extending a
>     circuit an arbitrary number of times. Every cell that goes down the
>     circuit then adds N times that amount of load in overall bandwidth
>     use. This vulnerability arises because servers don't know their position
>     on the path, so they can't tell how many nodes there are before them
>     on the path.
>
> We propose a new set of relay cells that are distinguishable by
>     intermediate hops as permitting extend cells. This approach will allow
>     us to put an upper bound on circuit length relative to the number of
>     colluding adversary nodes.
>
> Only K (say, 10) Relay_early cells can be sent across a circuit, and
>     only relay_early cells are allowed to contain extend requests. Each 
>     intermediate server would pass on the same type of cell that it
>     received (either relay or relay_early), and the cell's destination
>     will be able to learn whether it's allowed to contain an Extend request.
>
> If an intermediate server receives more than K relay_early cells, or
>     if it sees a relay cell that contains an extend request, then it
>     tears down the circuit (protocol violation).

Comment: I've already said this in the question ("circuit length is limited to 8"). I'm asking about getting the exit node to create another circuit. Tor lets you access HTTPS sites by having the exit node connect to TLS. Couldn't you use that to connect to TLS of another Tor entry guard?

Comment: @Victor No. Exit node will refuse to do that. *relay_early* cells are designed to prevent this, so that you can't ask a circuit to create extended circuits.

Comment: Again, I'm not talking about sending an EXTEND cell to the exit. I'm talking about sending an RELAY_BEGIN cell to the exit, and having the exit connect to another entry node.

Comment: You can absolutely do Tor-over-Tor...

Answer (score -1):

Nodes know how long the circuit chain is and TOR will not expand your chain beyond 8 cells. IIRC there is some sort of crypto based way to verify this.

Comment: As I asked in the question, couldn't you make a chain of 8 cells and then get the exit node to create a new circuit? The data for the new circuit should be invisible to the nodes before the exit node, as it should be encrypted.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. Yes you could, you could proxy through tor then create a new connection to tor though that proxy and so on and so on.